# How to make Multiple sub query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am new in Laravel.
    Here below i mention my code how to make this in laravel query builder.

Using tables are ab,cd,ef,gh,ij

```
 SELECT ab.* FROM ab
    WHERE ab.id IN (
      SELECT ab_id FROM cd
      WHERE ef_id = 1 AND status = 1
      AND deleted_at IS NULL
      AND ab_id IN (
        SELECT ab_id FROM gh
         WHERE ij_id IN (
            SELECT id FROM ij
            WHERE ef_id = 1 AND deleted_at IS NULL
        ) AND deleted_at IS NULL
      ) AND ab_id IN (
          SELECT id FROM ab
           WHERE deleted_at IS NULL AND usertest != 1
          )
      )AND ab.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY ab.id
ORDER BY ab.created_at DESC;
```

Comment: can you show your relation defined in model files.

Comment: you can do like this. `ab::with('cd.gh.ij.')->get()`. the table name and column name are not meaning full. so I cant define the relation ship between your tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a closure to a where condition and query another table.

From the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-exists-clauses):

```
DB::table('users')
            ->whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                      ->from('orders')
                      ->whereRaw('orders.user_id = users.id');
            })
            ->get();
```